# Unable to make the session state request to the session state server?

Tags: asp.net, session, web-hosting, stateserver

I am trying to use State Server sessions.

I have changed my Session state to the following:

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
```

Running my website from local host and everything works fine.

But when i publish my website and try run it online i get the following error:

> Unable to make the session state request to the session state server.
>   Please ensure that the ASP.NET State service is started and that the
>   client and server ports are the same.  If the server is on a remote
>   machine, please ensure that it accepts remote requests by checking the
>   value of
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\aspnet_state\Parameters\AllowRemoteConnection.
>   If the server is on the local machine, and if the before mentioned
>   registry value does not exist or is set to 0, then the state server
>   connection string must use either 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' as the
>   server name.

The website is hosted on Afrihost servers, after resarching the error i found that it could be because ASP.NET State service has not been started. Is there a way i could check if the Afrihost servers are running this service or to start it remotely?

Also i know the IP address 127.0.0.1 is for local host, but because you are publishing your application on webserver it becomes local to that machine is this correct.

Comment: Can you make an RDP connection on the server ? If so, make sure the service is properly started (in services.msc) and if it doesn't start correctly, check the Windows event log

Comment: @CharlesAD I don't think Afrihost allows RDP connections to there server, as they host most website for south africa.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That error message means the ASP.NET State service is not running.

Your connection string should always be `stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"` As wherever the site is hosted that will be the local machine.

After contacting Afrihost and asking them to restart the Service everything started to run fine.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's the correct answer. Please follow above suggestion. :)

Comment: Also make sure to set the Startup Type to Automatic, so you don't need to change it every time the server restarts.

Comment: i have the same error and cannoit start the service how it can be resolve

Comment: Unbelievable. Worked